# Is it possible to have one color for the upper wick and another color for the lower wick of the same candle?

Tags: pine-script

In plotcandle function i see only one wickcolor option, no distinction between upper and lower wicks.

For exemple on a bull candle i would like the big lower wick in green and the body + upper wick in grey

```
indicator("Only Wick", overlay=true)

BullBodyColor = color.rgb(169,169,169) // Grey
BullWickColor = color.rgb(169,169,169) // Grey
BullBigWick = color.lime // Vert 

isBigWickGreen = close>open and open-low > 1.5*(high-open)

//Normal Bull Candle :
plotcandle(bullCandle ? open : na , bullCandle ? high : na , bullCandle ? low : na , bullCandle ? close : na , color=BullBodyColor , wickcolor = BullWickColor, bordercolor= BullBodyColor ) 

// Bull Candle with rejection wick
plotcandle(isBigWickGreen ? open : na , isBigWickGreen ? high : na , isBigWickGreen ? low : na , isBigWickGreen ? close : na , color=BullBodyColor , wickcolor = BullBigWick, bordercolor= BullBodyColor )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately that is not possible.